# How to Filter large data when using skip and limit in MongoDB

Tags: python, database, mongodb, pymongo

I have an application that uses skip and limit functions of MongoDB in Python. It fetches data based on what is returned from the server and increments the skip and limit by 10 each time. However when I was trying to implement a filtering mechanism in my application, the filtering only applies to these ten items that I am getting returned. Can someone please tell me how can i retrieve the filtered data which is performed across the whole data that needs filtering rather than just the ten items? I need to be able to retrieve this data in skip and limit form. I cant seem to get my head around in trying to achieve this.

Here is an example function I am using for sorting for context

```
@app.route('/api/belowhundred/<country>/<skip>/<limit>',methods=['POST'])
def belowhundred(country,skip,limit):
products = db_products.find({'country':country}).skip(int(skip)).limit(int(limit))
prods = []
for product in products:
    if int(product['price']) <= 100:
        prods.append(product)
products = dumps(prods)
return products
```

Comment: Can you please provide sample data?

Comment: Put the filter before the limit in the aggregation.

Comment: @Joe I didnt quite get you

Answer (score 1):

Your query right now is:

- Apply filter C (country)
- Get the first 10 items matching filter C
- Apply filter P (price) (let's say 2 items match)
- Show the 2 items matching both filters to the user

You want:

- Apply both filters (C and P) to the entire collection
- Get the first 10 items that match both filters
- Show them to the user

To achieve this you need to filter by P on the server also. Try:

```
find({'country':country, 'price': {'$lt': 100}})
```

You need to use MongoDB query language (MQL) instead of Python operators to specify your conditions here.

Comment: Thanks for this! so if I wanted to sort the data on the entire collection will I use a sort function after my find() for eg -> find().sort().skip().limit() ?

Comment: Also when providing a filter in the find() returns to me empty collection even though there is data with items less than 100

Comment: You were casting price to int in your Python filter. Make sure you store the values as integers in MongoDB.